# Using OpenAi's Gym Java Client

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, openai-gym

I'm trying to utilise the Java port of OpenAi's gym - as I've been using Java instead of Python.

I've cloned [the gym's repo](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/tree/master/gym-java-client) which is a submodule of [the "mono-repo"](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j).

Within my project, in IntelliJ, I setup a dependency on the gym project (source code) but nothing's getting picked up.

After opening the gym project itself, within IntelliJ, none of the dependencies are being resolved, and the maven `pom.xml` file has a multitude of errors.

---

The first error is to the with the unrecognised parent module (the mono-repo).

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>deeplearning4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I tried setting up / building the mono-repo to no avail. I also was trying to figure out whether building the entire mono-repo was necessary - and not simply just including a *load* of redundant dependencies / modules.

Has anyone actually made use of this Java Client? 
The repo has extremely brief documentation, and I've not seen any example usages online

---

***EDIT***

Since posting this question the gym stuff has been removed from the deeplearning4j repository.

There still seems to be an implementation in the rl4j repository, which I've managed to pull as a maven dependency into my project.

When trying to run a basic cartpole example I get the error:

```
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection error
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at dentai.main.main(main.java:111)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection error
    at org.deeplearning4j.gym.ClientUtils.unirestCrash(ClientUtils.java:71)
    at org.deeplearning4j.gym.ClientUtils.post(ClientUtils.java:39)
    at org.deeplearning4j.gym.ClientFactory.build(ClientFactory.java:40)
    at org.deeplearning4j.gym.ClientFactory.build(ClientFactory.java:58)
    at org.deeplearning4j.rl4j.mdp.gym.GymEnv.<init>(GymEnv.java:46)
    at dentai.problems.CartPole.test(CartPole.java:18)
    at dentai.main.lambda$main$0(main.java:107)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:143)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
    at org.deeplearning4j.gym.ClientUtils.post(ClientUtils.java:37)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:138)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: It's gone, don't try to use it. Details here: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/pull/8595

Comment: @SamuelAudet This happened after this post was uploaded. I've spoken to devs of the repo regarding the `rl4j:gym-platform` alternative but haven't got any response

Comment: Please clarify your question. What issue are you having?

Comment: @SamuelAudet With rl4j, the current Issue im having is connection errors Ill update the question

Comment: `rl4j-gym` doesn't use `gym-java-client` anymore. It's simply not possible to get any connection errors. Make sure that you are using the snapshots correctly: https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-config-snapshots

Comment: @SamuelAudet I'm using `org.deeplearning4j:rl4j-gym:1.0.0-beta6`

Comment: I keep telling you *not* to use that. Use 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT!

Comment: @SamuelAudet `org.deeplearning4j:rl4j-gym:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` is not available on maven

Comment: Yes, it is: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/deeplearning4j/rl4j-gym/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: @SamuelAudet I eventually realised I had to add the external snapshots repository

Comment: @SamuelAudet I'm still struggling. I've imported the `deeplearning-core`, `deeplearning-modelimport` and `nd4j-native` artifacts from the snapshot repository as instructed by the tutorial at https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-config-snapshots; but, neither `org.deeplearning4j.gym` or `org.deeplearning4j.rl4j` can be resolved in my project. Do you know what the issue is?

Comment: I'm in the process of adding the `rl4j-gym` snapshot. But as seen in this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/UV8N78T.png its download loads of random Linux jars (im on windows). I'm running very low on space / resources is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Yes, there are a few Maven profiles for that: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Reducing-the-Number-of-Dependencies